# The actual meaning of projection

Tags: geometry

I was reading some geometry problems, and I have noticed something interesting about projections. Say we have a plane $\pi_{1}$, and a point A (a,b,c). We want to find the shortest distance between the plane and the point, which is straightforward:

Compute a "difference vector" between an arbitrary point in the plane and the point A (a,b,c) in question. Then, we can deduce a vector normal to the plane $\pi_{1}$ from the given equation of the plane. Now, we calculate the projection of this "difference vector" onto the normal vector, which will yield a vector that can give us the minimum distance.

However, what thrills me is the fact, can't we say that as well a scalar multiple of the normal vector is as well normal to this plane? Say we have a normal vector $n=(\alpha,\beta  ,\omega)$, can't we choose a really small scalar multiple of this normal vector? Say $n=(0.0001\alpha,0.0001\beta,0.0001\omega)$, and then calculate the projection of the difference vector onto this small normal vector? We would then get a really small vector which would not represent a "distance vector". How do we now that the normal vector $n$ is actually "larger" to the minimum distance between a point and a plane? I have encountered this as well when dealing with minimum distance between two perpendicular lines.

I do understand how the process works, but I want to be sure HOW can we assume that the normal vector is a suitable one to do the projection.

Comment: The projection removes the component parallel to the normal, regardless of the length of the normal (which must be non-zero).

Comment: Yes, however wouldn't the vector then have a small component parallel to the normal?

Comment: The different vector will be the same, the component along the normal will depend on the length and direction (as in $\pm$) of the normal. For example, if the component along $n$ is $\alpha$, then the component along $0.1 n$ will be $10 \alpha$.

Comment: Being a liberal.

Answer (score 1):

You just compute the [scalar product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product) between any vector $\vec{AP}$ with $P\in\pi$ and the normal vector renormalized to have length 1.

Comment: You are right: i did a calculation involving a constant "a" for the normal vector, but how can we see the actual meaning of projection geometrically when we have a really small multiple of the normal vector? I get that algebraically it still holds, but i want to know why geometrically.

Comment: As I said, you need to understand the geometric meaning of the scalar product (link provided to the wiki page).